# How to write interpretation of an expression in Java

Tags: java, expression

So here is the part of my code:

```
if (file.toString().??? && file.toString().endsWith(FilterCommand.afterDot)) {
            System.out.println(file.toAbsolutePath());
```

User will enter string, something like this(somet*ext.txt is just an example of one input, user will input several times and every time it can be something different): somet*ext.txt and my job is to find all files which match given expression. In this example it may be something like this:

```
sometext.txt
sometHhBkJnKext.txt
sometANYTHINGCANBEHEREext.txt
```

So "somet" and "ext.txt" remains constant. In between them anything can be there. I mean 0 or more characters. We can also assume that user will never input two *. It will always be one * and it can be at front, in the middle or in the end.

I am able to separate given string on string before dot(somet*ext, I save it in variable `FilterCommand.beforeDot`) and after dot(txt, I save it in variable `FilterCommand.afterDot`). So, in if I need to ask if the text after dot is same (I use:`file.toString().endsWith(FilterCommand.afterDot)` and if the text before dot match given expression. How can I do it?

Comment: I apologize, I did not express myself well. * represents zero or many any letters. For example * can mean: fgdKSS, or DDS, or fff. It is not importnat if it is uppercase or lowercase.

Comment: What does `**` mean?

Comment: User will never input something like that so we can ignore that case.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I believe he is just showing that there will be any characters between `somet*****ext` just easier to visually see with the `**` separating it from the rest of the text.

Comment: So "somet" and "ext.txt" remains constant ? In between them anything can be there. I mean 0 or more characters right ??

Comment: @AritroSen you are right!

Comment: @MyNameIsNemo did you try my answer?

Comment: @brso05 Give me some time, I am trying all the answers I get. Btw. I edited my post a bit

Answer (score 4):

So i think you can just do something like this -

```
if(file.toString().matches("somet.*ext\\.txt")){
        System.out.println(file.toAbsolutePath());
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Not matching");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check it like this (This will also match the `.txt` so no need to split the filename):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    if(Pattern.matches("somet.*ext\\.txt", "somet**HhBkJnK**ext.txt"))
    {
        System.out.println("Yes");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("No");
    }
    if(Pattern.matches("somet.*ext\\.txt", "sometext.txt"))
    {
        System.out.println("Yes");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("No");
    }
    if(Pattern.matches("somet.*ext\\.txt", "some**sdfsdfsdft**ex.txt"))
    {
        System.out.println("Yes");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("No");
    }
}
```

Output:

> Yes
>
> Yes
>
> No

Just do this to check with your file:

```
if(Pattern.matches("somet.*ext\\.txt", file.toString()))
{
    System.out.println("Yes");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("No");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to escape the dot, i.e. \. otherwise the regex parser will interpret the dot as 'find a single character, any character'.

For example:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

     String regexFilePattern = "[[a-zA-Z0-9]+]\\.[[a-zA-Z0-9]+]";

     Matcher matcher = null;


  for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
  matcher = Pattern.compile(regexFilePattern).matcher(args[i]);
    while (matcher.find()) {
         if (matcher.start() > 0) {
              //there is a match!
              //manipulate the result here when the text after the dot
              //matches the text before the dot
         }
    }
  }


}
```

Comment: In string that user inputs there can only be one *, it can be at beginning of the string, somewhere in the middle or at the end. I edited my post.

Comment: if that's the case then add the following to the regular expression so that it look as follows: somet[[a-zA-Z0-9]+]ext.txt

Comment: somet*ext.txt is just an example of one input, user will input several times and every time it can be something different. I edited my orginal post.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure why you would need to split the string that the user provides you at the '.'. It seems like you could just write `file.toString().matches(userString)`to determine if that file matches the provided pattern